# Customize "event" in calendar View

Tags: calendar

I would like to have my calendar view display a "tick" or a small "dot" to signal that a given day has events instead of the standart "Hour+Event Name" block... is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is possible, but not necessarily out of the box. This could be done using a variety of techniques. One option would be to use javascript/css to swap the visible items after loading. You could also build a custom view using xslt if you are familiar with it.